SET Variables in HIVE from function
I'm trying to insert data into a Hive table with a dynamic partition value that needs to be a computed date, but Hive's PARTITION clause doesn't seem to support expressions or functions.
I have a base date, say '2024-11-04' and I want to calculate the next day ('2024-11-05') and use it as a partition value. so I try to use functions like DATE_ADD or date_format directly in the PARTITION clause, I get errors because Hive requires a literal string.
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table 
PARTITION (date_time=DATE_ADD(TO_DATE('2024-11-04', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 1))
SELECT * FROM source_table;


Error

Error in query: Syntax error at or near '(' (line 3, pos 92)
== SQL ==
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table 
PARTITION (date_time=DATE_ADD(TO_DATE('2024-11-04', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 1))
I also tried assigning the computed date to a Hive variable:


I also tried assigning the computed date to a Hive variable:

SET partition_date = date_format(date_add(to_date('2024-11-04', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table 
PARTITION (date_time='${hiveconf:partition_date}')
SELECT * FROM source_table;

But it still treats it as a function rather than a literal string.
seems same issue mentioned here as well

I would use a '.sh' file and pass my hive query as either hive -e 'query' or hive -f 'query.hql'
In bash, it would be very easy to achieve you require.
